# In rails while looping with .each how to group records with similar properties?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have some time based packages like this :

```
Timepackage.create!(name: 'Bronze', months: 1, downloads: 50, price: 40)
Timepackage.create!(name: 'Silver', months: 1, downloads: 100, price: 60)
Timepackage.create!(name: 'Gold', months: 1, downloads: 150, price: 80)
Timepackage.create!(name: 'Bronze', months: 3, downloads: 50, price: 140)
Timepackage.create!(name: 'Silver', months: 3, downloads: 100, price: 160)
Timepackage.create!(name: 'Gold', months: 3, downloads: 150, price: 180)
```

I need to loop through each of them `@timepackages.each do` and print them out. While doing that, I need to pick packages which have same amount of months into one row. For example if someone add a nother 1 months plan, it should come to after the 1 month gold plan. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the answers. But if we just sort, I can't group and label the plans as 1 month plan, 2 month plan like that.... So, here's what I did :

```
    @months = Timepackage.pluck(:months).uniq
    @monthsHash = {}
    @months.each do |month|
        @monthsHash.merge!("#{month}" => Timepackage.where(months: month.to_i))
    end
```

I got the months to an array. Then created a hash to group the plans. The key is the month and the value is the collection of records which have that month. Now all I have to do is loop through the hash... Take the month, add it to the label, then loop through the plans it have and print them out liek this :

```
      <% @monthsHash.each do |month| %>
        <h3><%= month[0] %> Month Plans</h3>
        <div class="row">
          <% month[1].each_with_index do |package, i| %>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 <%= "package#{i}" %> <%= "big" if i == 1 %>">
              <div class="pricing-table">
                <div class="pricing-header">
                  <p class="pricing-title"><%= package.name %></p>
                  <p class="pricing-rate"><sup>$</sup> <%= number_with_precision(package.price, precision: 0 ) %> <span>.00</span></p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-custom">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pricing-list">
                  <ul>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i><span><%= package.downloads %> Downloads</span></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Valid for <%= pluralize(package.months, 'month') %></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>Buy non exclusive photos</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <br>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Ah great thanks! I'll try it out and let you know :D

Answer (score 2):

What you're talking about is *sorting*. You just need to sort the results prior to looping:

```
@timepackages.sort_by { |t| t.months }.each do
  # ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this as well...

```
@timepackages.sort_by(&:months).each do
  # ...
```

**EDIT**

```
# This gives a hash of arrays with month as key
@timepackages.group_by(&:months).each do
  # ...
```

As far as I see, the group_by is sorting based on id of activerecord. So, if someone adds another one month plan it will be after the gold plan only. If you want to add a plan in between then u might have to think of sorting inside the each of group by